# I am trying to get the start and end for 10 weeks. But it is printing the the same values for all weeks. I cant find the problem. Thank you

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    week_milli_seconds = []
    week_time = []
    startDate = new Date(2020, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0)
    startTime = startDate.getTime()
    endTime = startTime + (week_milli_seconds - 1)
    
    for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        week_time.push({Start : startTime, End: endTime})
        startTime += week_milli_seconds
        endTime += week_milli_seconds
    }
    
    // console.log(startTime)
    // console.log(endTime)
    
    totalStartTime = new Date(2020, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0)
    totalEndtime = Date.now()
    
    console.log(week_time)

  { Start: 1597636800000, End: 1597636799999 },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' },
  { Start: '1597636800000', End: '1597636799999' }
]
```

This is the result I'm getting but I am trying to get different values for the different weeks I tried the += operator but it is not working. Thank you in advance

Comment: are starttime and endTime `var` `let` or `const`?

Comment: `(week_milli_seconds - 1)` <= subtracting an integer `1` from an `array` is weird

Comment: I havent put anything but I will change them to let

Comment: can you please edit to have a reproduction code and not parts of it?

Comment: `week_milli_seconds` is an (empty) array but you everywhere seem to want to treat it as if it's a number. Are you sure it's actually defined the way you show here?

Answer (score 2):

An empty array is assigned to `week_milli_seconds`.
The `+` operator when given a number and an array concatenates each members of the array and the number to a string:

```
12 + [1,2,3] // "121,2,3"
```

Since your array is empty, it's equivalent to concatenating a number to `""`.

You should initialise `week_milli_seconds` to `604 800 000 (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7)`

Comment: This is the more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

`week_milli_seconds` is an empty array. So your `+=` operator is trying to add an empty array to the time which just returns the original time again, but as a string. Change it to `week_milli_seconds = 604800000`.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off `week_milli_seconds = []`, is an array, yet you are adding it to different numbers, Im guessing you wanted it to be set to the total number of milliseconds in a week, to do that

`week_milli_seconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7`

Im not so familiar with the Date library but assuming `startDate.getTime()` returns a `long` type date string similar to Date.now, but relative to that time, then it should work now

Answer (score 0):

You never set the variable `week_milli_seconds`, so how shall it work? You have to give it a value, so you can increase or decrease another variable with that value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that week_milli_seconds is an array. Consider assigning some value to it instead of an empty array.

The following code should work.

```js
let week_milli_seconds = 604800000
let week_time = []
let startDate = new Date(2020, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0)
let startTime = startDate.getTime()
let endTime = startTime + (week_milli_seconds - 1)
    
for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  week_time.push({Start : startTime, End: endTime})
  startTime += week_milli_seconds
  endTime += week_milli_seconds
}
    
    
console.log(week_time)
```